# Getting PHP to exec PHP

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I'm trying to fork a process by getting PHP to exec PHP whilst piping output to /dev/null and running the cmd in the background

Before I get this running silently - I want to check the cmd runs as expected - however when the command is executed by PHP the process (both master and forked) never terminate and the browser is forver stuck on "Connecting..."

Here is the code:

```
$script = '/home/username/application/bg_job.php';
$args = 'foo bar';

$cmd = "php -f $script $args";
$return = exec($cmd, $arr_output, $code);

var_dump($return);
```

I checked the Apache user which runs the script by doing

```
whoami
```

and it was "username" - so I've logged in as root and run

```
sudo -u username php -f /home/username/application/bg_job.php foo bar
```

And it works.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT - FYI - here is the contents of bg_job.php

```
<?php
    file_put_contents('/home/username/test.txt', 'Hello !');
?>
```

Comment: do you want to run this from browser (as in ur description) or from cli (as in ur tags)

Comment: The CLI code is just to show that the script does run (no syntax or permission errors) - it will be the browser that invokes the child process

Comment: Most probably you are running into permission errors. Since you actually invoke your command via web browser i.e. RUN_USER=www-data and RUN_GROUP=www-data, your background script MUST have necessary bit set so that your web process can execute your bg_job.php. Also the output file which you expect bg_job.php to write, must also have correct permission bit set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are attempting to instigate a background task. On Linux this can be done with the [ampersand](http://www.astro.ku.dk/comp-phys/tutorials/background.shtml):

```
php -f /var/file.php &
```

There are more details on [this blog post](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-background-process-in-php.html).

So your command would become:

```
$cmd = "php -f $script $args &";
```

Comment: Tried - no change - yes I will be making this a background task - but only when it works. Even with the & - my child script never runs :(

Comment: Oh I didn't get that from your question. I thought you said it was running and would hold your Apache process open waiting for the `exec` to come back. See: `however when the command is executed by PHP the process (both master and forked) never terminate and the browser is forver stuck on "Connecting..."`. That more than implies that it is working.

Comment: But it's not working - all bg_job.php does is write to a text file - yet that text file never gets created.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is that if you want to get a background process to run, you have to use `proc_open`.

Why this works this way I've fully yet to understand, but whenever you close a proc resource the program does not end executing.

It will also, if done correctly, not cause anything to hang.

This is what I mean.

```
$sCommand = "php -f /home/username/application/bg_job.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &";

$aPipes = array();

$rProcedure = proc_open($sCommand, array(), $aPipes);
proc_close($rProcedure);
```

You'll see that it'll run in the background, and won't die when Apache finishes doing what it does.